# Integration of $5^{x + \tan^{-1} x}$ wrt $dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int5^{x + \tan^{-1} x}dx$$

I tried substituting $x + \tan^{-1} x = u $ and proceed but this substitution doesn't work well, this just makes the integration complicated. I am not able to solve this , and I'll be glad to have your help to solve it.

Comment: You're not going to find a closed form solution, so if you have a definite integral, numerical methods are the only way to go.

Comment: Wolfram alpha shows no closed form solution.

Comment: i think there is no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: So, you mean to say that we cannot find its indefinite integration

Comment: Even using special functions, we cannot get the antiderivative. Are you sure that you are not asked to *approximate* the definite integral between some bounds ?